# Fixed frame rate using android Camera2 api

Tags: android, frame-rate, android-camera2

I'm very new to android. I'm trying to develop an application using android camera2 api and i want to maintain a steady frame rate for that. I could not find any example on how to achieve a fixed frame rate.

By experimenting i can see that application gets around 5-7 FPS. but it's varying. A detailed method to get a fixed frame rate is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "i want to maintain a steady frame rate for that" -- a steady frame rate for what? Capturing preview frames? Capturing full still photos? Capturing video with `MediaRecorder`? Something else?

Comment: sorry about being low on details. i'm doing some image processing on preview frames. I'm processing the frames inside the onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) method available in ImageReader. I need to get steady frame rate for that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the [AE target FPS range](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE) to what you want?
What resolution are you trying to read?

On LEGACY-level devices, higher resolutions may run slow due to format conversion in the guts of the camera legacy stack.